# Injecting a CDI interceptor into a beans does not work

Tags: java, cdi, weld

I have created a CDI (WELD) interceptor that works and intercept what it is supposed to intercept.

```
@MyInterceptorBinding
@Interceptor
@Dependent
public class MyInterceptor implements Serializable {

    private int myIntegerField;
    
    @AroundInvoke
    public Object interceptMethod(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {

        // Do some operations and side effects on myIntegerField;

        try {
            Object result = ctx.proceed();
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public List<Class<?>> getMyIntegerField() {
        return myIntegerField;
    }

}
```

Where MyInterceptorBinding is an interceptor binding:

```
@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyInterceptorBinding {}
```

I would like to inject my interceptor into a bean class like this:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private MyInterceptor interceptor;

    public void aMethod(){
        int var = interceptor.getMyIntegerField();
        // use var in some way...
   }
}
```

but this injection brings to an error:

```
Unsatisfied dependencies for type MyInterceptor with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private trials.MyBean.interceptor
```

How can i overcome this issue? Is a problem related to the fact that is an interceptor?
Should i use the CDI portable extension facility? And, if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't inject interceptors because they aren't beans. What you probably can do is create a helper bean and inject that in both the interceptor and the application scoped bean. That helper bean can then contain the value, the interceptor can set it and the other bean can read it.

A warning about scopes: your `MyBean` is application scoped, which means that there will be only once instance. If the interceptor is used in request scoped beans, what should the value of the interceptor value be? For this to work, the helper bean should most likely also be application scoped, and you should take care of thread safety.

Comment: Just a question before I accept your answer: why only @ApplicationScoped beans can be injected into interceptor? Here the stacktrace with SessionScoped: `WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
    Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: org.jboss.weld.contexts.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.contexts.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped"}}`

Comment: `@SessionScoped` is tied to a session. That means that the interceptor would only work with an active session. For the same reason, `@RequestScoped` may also fail. That would mean that the state you store isn't going to be thread safe.